# How to count distinct values from two columns into one number

Tags: mysql, sql

The two tables I'm working on are these:

Submissions:

```
+----+------------+
| id | student_id |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          1 |
|  2 |          2 |
|  3 |          3 |
+----+------------+
```

Group_submissions:

```
+----+---------------+------------+
| id | submission_id | student_id |
+----+---------------+------------+
|  1 |             1 |          2 |
|  2 |             2 |          1 |
+----+---------------+------------+
```

Only one student actually makes the submission and goes into the submissions table while the others go to the group_submissions table(if the submission is a group submission)

I want to count the unique number of students that have made submission either as a group or alone

I want just the number to be returned in the end (3 based on the data on the tables above)

A student that is in the submissions table should not be counted twice if he is in the group_submission table and vice-versa.

Also students that only have done individual submissions(that are not in the group_submissions table) also should be counted regardless if the have ever been in a group submission

I'm already doing some other operations on these table in a query I'm building so if you can give me a solution based on joining these two tables that would help.

This is what i have tried:

```
count(distinct case when group_submissions.student_id is not null then group_submissions.student_id end) + count(distinct case when submissions.student_id is not null then submissions.student_id end)
```

But it gives me duplicates so if a student is in both tables he is counted two times.

Any ideas?

NOTE: This is a MySQL database.

Comment: Have to tried  `LEFT JOIN` ,`COUNT` & `DISTINCT`

Comment: Please share your attempt in writing SQL. Getting homework solved on the forum won't help in your learning

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: I think i already explained the expected result where i said i wanted only the number to be returned and added this : ``` (3 based on the data on the tables above)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `union` and a count:

```
select count(*)
from ((select student_id
       from submissions
      ) 
      union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select student_id
       from group_submissions
      )
     ) s;
```

Comment: Joins are not the right way to go about it then? I have some other tables already joined into these two tables and am doing some operations based on those tables.
But if this is the only way I'll figure out something.

Answer (score 0):

After listening to the clarification, I think it is not wise to force yourself to compute this using the join. You can instead make the count just a simple expression as the final outcome. Use UNION and then distinct will help for building such an expression.

OLD ANSWER BELOW THAT DOES NOT FIT THE PROBLEM:

> Very simple fix is needed to your current version...
>
> ```
> count(distinct case when group_submissions.student_id is not null then
> group_submissions.student_id when assignment_submissions.student_id is
> not null then assignment_submissions.student_id end)
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> - your original expression is an addition between 2 case expressions,    each with a single WHEN inside
> - now I turn it into a single case expression with 2 WHEN's```SQL

Comment: And what, exactly, is that `simple fix`? Code-only answers tend to be low quality, both for the current user asking the question and for future users with similar issues. An explanation of your solution adds significant value to your answer.

Comment: @EricBrandt I added a note...hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't work because the case statement will short circuit once the first condition is met.

For example:

If one student has done group submissions but has never actually done the submission he/she will be displayed on the group_submissions table only.

So if on the submissions table the id is 1 and on the group_submission table the id is 2, and id 2 does not occur on the submissions table it will not be counted.
I'll edit the question to make this a bit clearer

Comment: Oh, so you do mean the submission_id is the FK to id of the submission table? So for example it is possible that student 3 appears in multiple rows of the group_submission table, each submitted by another group member? If that is the case, I think you will need an additional join just for making the count. Overall, I will not recommend to count it within the join, better make it a separate expression using something like the other answer.